# Watch in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a jsFiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/3qxKK/.
Why the watch is never called when I changed an input value?

Maybe because "results" is not an object (but I put the parameter "true"):

```
$scope.results = [];
angular.forEach($scope.services, function(service) {
    $scope.results[service.id] = '';
});
```

Besides, "results" in the template is always displayed as "[]".
It's strange because the value next the input is refreshed...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about changing it to an object ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3qxKK/1/))?

```
$scope.results = {};
```

You've used an array.

Comment: Thanks! :) I know this but this time I lost half an hour on it.